# Using AJAX to require a specific php file

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have 3 clickable menu items on my page:

> - option1
> - option2
> - option3

I also have 3 php files on my server:

> - option1.php
> - option2.php
> - option3.php

To keep things simple, let's say option1.php echoes the number 1, option2.php echoes the number 2, etc.

To avoid the page refreshing, I want to use AJAX, so when a user clicks option1, option1.php file will display the number 1. I hope I have made myself clear.

What is a good way to do this?

**EDIT:** I've reviewed my question again and have come up with a solution.
In my php file that contains my menu items I added an update area div.

```
<div id="update_area">
</div>
```

My external javascript file contains onclick events which call a function that sends the menu item number to be processed by my AJAX php file. This tests my

```
$_GET[sent_data]
```

and if (for example) it equals 1, then it uses

```
require "option1.php";
```

Now that the functionality is working I can independently edit my option?.php files.

I've voted SomeKittens answer as the one that was most helpful.

Comment: This is exactly how AJAX works - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I assume you meant to link [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Sorry about not posting "what have you tried". I will review the answers given and add more useful information and votes etc later. My user level is novice btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point during your JavaScript code that sends the AJAX data back to the PHP, you'll need to specify what PHP file you'll be sending the data to.  In vanilla JS, this is the [`ajaxRequest.open`](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php) portion.  Have your AJAX function take a string parameter (say `phpfile`) and then use the following snippet to select the php file in your AJAX function:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", phpfile, true);
```

Your form elements would have the attrib `onclick`:

```
onClick="myAJAX('option1.php')"
```

etc, etc.

http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/

Comment: Downvoter want to explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I'll look at this method also and return to give votes once I figure it out. I'm new to this, so I need to understand the answers first. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely.  That's why I linked to the tutorial.  (though next time, please Google it first.)

Comment: @liverpaul https://gist.github.com/3086939

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point of Javascript and HTML to retrieve data and display it on a page using AJAX.

**Javascript** (after you include jQuery)

```
function getDataForOption(num) {
    $.ajax(function() {
        url: "option" + num + ".php",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="results"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="getDataForOption(1);">Option 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getDataForOption(2);">Option 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getDataForOption(3);">Option 3</a>
```

Comment: I will mess around with this method and once (or if) I have it working I will return and vote the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: you should mention that this approach uses jQuery

Comment: jQuery, ok. I guess I'll try a different answer for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
  $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(r) { $('#container').html(r) });
});
```

Comment: Not doing things in jQuery these days is like going the long way when you can just take the shortcut.  It's very lightweight, so it shouldn't be considered overkill, either.

Comment: [jQuery makes you a bad developer](http://recoding.blogspot.com/2012/10/why-jquery-doesnt-work.html)

Comment: it is overkill, developers use it as a crutch and don't learn how it works. and the argument "why reinvent the wheel" is bogus, learn your craft or find a new hobby

Comment: As mentioned, I won't be using jQuery, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Someone who programs using jQuery is not that much worse than someone who chooses to use pure Javascript.  Isn't programming much more about problem solving than doing things the hard way.  Heck, why not just write everything in machine code?  Because, higher level languages and libraries make things easier.

Comment: sure, jQuery is one of some possible good choices for a js framework. Still, it is a framework and not the required technique itself. Users, that offer answers in jQuery when the OP clearly doesn't know much js, should at least mention why they use jQuery...and that their answer requires jQuery to start with!

Comment: My opinion is use libraries to get it work, but learn how do they do it.

Comment: jQuery is not a framework. sorry had to mention it. It is not a bad library, it just causes so many people to not understand javascript because they use jQuery as a crutch. and please don't include the entire library for one or two of its functions. There are smaller, compact, specific libs for this.

Comment: @rlemon totally agree, if one wants to really learn web programming, s/he should learn javascript from scratch, to understand, how this language works. Still, for a real application that uses complex client side functions, I would always use a cross browser compatible framework, jQuery, dojo, ext, prototype....

Comment: I think you guys have nothing to worry about because one must know javascript to some extent even to use jQuery.  You still must learn JS syntax and variable declaration, array functions, etc. to use jQuery.

Comment: ah yes, I can't get around using library and framework interchangeable, especially when it concerns javascript

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript for continued discussion on the misconceptions that jQuery brings.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need to use AJAX. When someone clicks on option1, it will pass the value of the option to a function. This value will decide on which page, the request should go. Send the request though AJAX, and onSuccess, display the output.